# Visual studio showing wrong syntax highlighting color when loading multiple instances at the same time

Tags: colors, visual-studio-2017

I have DARK mode enabled on my visual studio IDE and on windows 10 configurations.

To reproduce the "bug" I :

- open multiple instances (4) of visual studio as admin. (If prompted to ask permission, I click yes)
- go on each instances' start page and under Recent solution/project I select projects as fast as I can
- wait for each project/solution to load up on each instances
- see strange highlights/color, in the IDE, on the code I wrote on each project/solution.

It's as if the IDE is displaying colors of the LIGHT mode while still being on DARK mode.

Example of "normal" DARK mode IDE:
[image]
[image]

Example of "bugged" DARK mode/With LIGHT syntax highlights IDE:
[image]
[image]

**QUESTION :**
Is there any way to fix this bug other than closing and reopening all the IDEs I opened too fast?

Comment: This may be not a bug. I have this issue all the time with VS19. Wait some time after Visual Studio loads the solution/project. Then it will automatically shows correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Biswapriyo even after waiting for a couple of minutes, the syntax highlighting stays the same ): Maybe it's because I'm with vs2017

Comment: Try to start VS in [SafeMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019). If this helps, then the problem is with some extension. In [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/750961/dark-theme-elements-mixed-in-blue-theme.html) the problem was caused by VisualGDB.

Comment: @harrymc The "bug" is still happening in safe mode, but only half the time. *EDIT:* I retested without safe mode and it's the same

Comment: Try to find which extension causes it in half of the times. This might give some indication.

Comment: I don't understand the Edit : Is there no difference in safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc There is differences in safe mode but opening multiple IDE instance of projects while in safe mode still makes the syntax color wrong. Just to be clear, I added the /SafeMode sufix to my windows desktop shortcut execution target and used this shortcut to open visual studio multiple times.

Comment: The extension then seems only to change somewhat the behavior, not to cause it. I'm afraid that the only thing you can do is signal the problem to Microsoft. I wonder if forcing a delay between opening instances will help as a workaround.

Comment: @harrymc I'll go ahead and do what you said. I'll report this behaviour/bug to Microsoft (: Meanwhile, I guess I'll just wait a bit more between each opening of my multiple projects. Thanks for your help/tips. It's really appreciated. Just answer saying that I need to report this bug to Microsoft and I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: Answer added as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much that can be done when having a problem with Visual Studio.
One can hope that the problem is with some extension that can be disabled
as a fix. To test this, start Visual Studio in
[SafeMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019):

```
devenv /SafeMode
```

If the problem has been solved, then the solution is simply to find the
bad extension.

In the case that the problem is still there, then the only action possible is
to send Microsoft a bug report.
For this, see the Microsoft article
[How to report a problem with Visual Studio or Visual Studio Installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Then one needs to search for some workaround, because bugs in Visual Studio
are not fixed that rapidly.